# Unable to trim string received from TCP stream

Tags: string, rust

I just started learning Rust today, but I've been programming for a while now ... Yet, I can't seem to trim a simple string in Rust. I tried using slicing `&[0 .. length - 2]`, `trim()`, `trim_right()`, nothing seems to help...

So, `stream` here is a `TCPStream`, and even though I am using `trim()`, the output of the following code is:

```sh
# client
$ nc localhost 3500
hello
$ ...
# server output
Received string: hello
, Rust! ..
```

---

```
let mut buffer = [0; 2048];
let _ = stream.read(&mut buffer);
let s = format!("{}, Rust!", String::from_utf8_lossy(&buffer).trim());

println!("Received string: {} ..", s);
```

**Update:** Seems like the `from_utf8_lossy` is returning a string of length 2048! When I send a string long enough, and take a slice, it finally works...

Just in case, here is the full source:

https://gist.github.com/Mazyod/8f6807e2c859b3457eaa4bcf24d5d703

Comment: @Neikos I am sending the string "hello" down the write using `nc`, that verifies it is reading something, right?

Comment: Yes, I misread the code and didn't see you used `format` instead of `println`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, what's happening here?
Let's see that example:

```
fn main() {
    let mut buffer = [0; 32];
    buffer[0] = b'H';
    buffer[1] = b'i';
    buffer[2] = b'!';
    buffer[3] = b'\n';

    println!("{:?}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&buffer));
}
```

This shows:

```
"Hi!\n\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}"
```

No wonder `trim` does not work!

[`Read::read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#tymethod.read) returns the number of read characters, use it, don't ignore it!

Comment: Both answers are great, but since this was first ... I also discovered `read_line`, which may work without dealing with this low level representation.

Answer (score 11):

Using the code provided in the gist this seems to be wrong:

1. [`Read::read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html#tymethod.read) returns a result which you are ignoring, this could be a problem later on.
2. You are giving `String::from_utf8_lossy` the whole buffer even if it might only be be somewhat full. So what might happen that it scans from the end, but your string is all at the beginning. 
   Imagine a buffer like this: `['H','e','\n',\0,'4','d']` you only put in  the `"He\n"` but String doesn't care and still uses the whole length of the buffer.

To fix it you can do something like this:

```
let n = try!(stream.read(&mut buffer));
let s = format!("{}, Rust!", String::from_utf8_lossy(&buffer[0..n]).trim());

println!("Received string: {} ..", s);
```

Which uses the [Range](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/struct.Range.html) syntax to take a slice up to the last actually read character.

Comment: As a side note, it is generally a bad idea to hard-ignore errors, handle them or bubble them up. (With `try!` for example)